# Broken Arrow in Lucida Bright Font

Tags: fonts, arrows

When I attempt to use any kind of "long" arrow in the Lucida Bright font, it ends up coming out broken. For a MWE Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}      
\usepackage{unicode-math}  

\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setsansfont{Lucida Sans OT}
\setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter OT}

\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}

\begin{document}

Here is an example of an arrow which looks weird:

\begin{gather}
\widehat{\mathcal{O}_v}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_v} k\xrightarrow{\approx}\widehat{k}
\end{gather}

here is another example:

\begin{gather}
\varprojlim k[T]/(T^n)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\xrightarrow` and `\varprojlim` commands use a minus sign for extending the arrow; in the Lucida Math font this has not the same height as the arrow; you can use a different symbol, though, namely "HORIZONTAL LINE EXTENSION U+23AF", that's available in `unicode-math` under the name `\harrowextender`; just redefine `\relbar` to use it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}      
\usepackage{unicode-math}  

\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setsansfont{Lucida Sans OT}
\setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter OT}

\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}

\renewcommand{\relbar}{\mathrel{\harrowextender}}

\begin{document}


Here is an example of an arrow which looks weird:
\[
\widehat{\mathcal{O}_v}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_v} k\xrightarrow{\approx}\widehat{k}
\]
here is another example:
\[
\varprojlim k[T]/(T^n)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, I don't think `amssymb` does any good with `unicode-math`.

Comment: This did not work for me using XeLaTeX and TeX Gyre Pagella as maths font.  The extended part of the arrow is invisible.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Unfortunately, none of the TeX Gyre math fonts has the glyph; just don't redefine `\relbar` and you should be OK

Comment: The reason I found this question/answer is that actually it's not OK.  I get an ugly dashed arrow when I use \xrightarrow.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill I'm afraid it's a bug in TeX Gyre Pagella, then: they *should* provide U+23AF

Comment: How can I go about checking whether a given font has that glyph?

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Just do `\renewcommand{\relbar}{\mathrel{-}}` for TeX Gyre Pagella.

Comment: @egreg: Many thanks!  That works fine.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

try this setting:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}  
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setsansfont{Lucida Sans OT}
\setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter OT}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}
\setmathfont[range={"2190,"2192,"2212}]{TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular}
```

or alternatively to using Pagella

```
\makeatletter
\ams@def\relbar{\raisebox{-0.35pt}{$-$}}
\makeatother
```

(after loading `amsmath`). Here is my complete test example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}  
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setsansfont{Lucida Sans OT}
\setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter OT}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}
\setmathfont[range={"2190,"2192,"2212}]{XITS Math}
%\makeatletter
%\ams@def\relbar{\raisebox{-0.35pt}{$-$}}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}        
\begin{gather}
\widehat{\mathcal{O}_v}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_v} k\xrightarrow{\approx}\widehat{k}
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
\varprojlim k[T]/(T^n)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am getting an error when I try to implement this code though. It says that the font "TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular" cannot be found, and that I should reference the "fontspec" documentation (I am using fontspec). Also, when I try your second fix it says that "\relbar" is not defined.

Comment: Which TeX-system do you have? And did you updated it? You can also use `XITS Math` instead. See my edited answer for a complete document

Comment: Herbert, I apologize if I am misunderstanding you. I am using Tex Shop for Mac. I don't know what XITS Math is, as well.

Comment: XITS is a font and should be installed by default. With MacTeX you can also update your system. However, if you use `xelatex` (I used `lualatex`) you have to use as name `xits-math.otf` instead of the symbolic name `XITS Math`

Comment: Herbert, I apologize for being so dense, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement your suggestions. Is XITS Math some kind of package I need to include? Do I need to download it? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexYoucis: no problem to ask. XITS Math is a font and it should be already on your system in the TeX folder. But xetex can find fonts in that folder only when using by its file name. lualatex can find it also by its symbolic name. You can test it: open a terminal and  run `kpsewhich xits-math.otf` If you get _no_ output then the font file is not installed. But it should be if you run the update manager of MacTeX.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8035/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-herbert)