# How to use the extended arrows in unicode-math

Tags: xetex, luatex, arrows, unicode-math

As we all know, the long arrows can be used with `amsmath` or `extarrows`: `\xleftarrow`, `\xLongleftarrow` etc.

However, these macros simply employ minus or equals and may not be so pretty. With `unicode-math`, for example, XITS Math has defined the long arrows with OpenType feature horizontal construction. How to use it in LaTeX?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218388/4427 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103900/4427 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191274/4427

Comment: @egreg but they are still putting the extension together via tex rather than via the OTF table aren't they?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then `unicode-math` should provide the good code for `\xleftarrow` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Luatex has a `\Uhextensible` primitive to access horizontal stretch feature in the font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}



\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}


\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

$\Uhextensible width 5cm 0 "2192$

$\Uhextensible width 6cm 0 "2194$

$\Uhextensible width 7cm 0 "21D2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think the horizontal extension mechanism is available in xetex

Comment: It seems that `\Uhextensible` is only available in luatex.

Comment: And how to add text under/below the arrow?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng text above and below you would do as in (the definition o)f the x... arrows from amsmath so `$\mathop{\Uhextensible width 5cm 0 "2192}\limits_{\mathrm{text}}$`  it would need a proper top level command defining but partly as it only works in luatex this hasn't been used much I expect. It works though.